# Convert or Download a Youtube/Vimeo iframe src url Video to a HTML5 video tag source for show on my Wordpress Website

Tags: php, html, wordpress, iframe, html5-video

i'm looking for a possibility for my Wordpress page to convert or convert a Youtube/Vimeo iframe src link/url so that it can be output either as a temporary file or as a link in an html5 video source tag. I know there is a possibility, because there is a plugin called Smartvideo https://swarmify.com/features/auto-youtube-export/ and it works here too.

So here is the code again as I would like it to be:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/$video_id" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

convert/download temporary to

```
<video muted autoplay loop>
    <source src="https://domain.de/transformed_video/$video_id.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I hope there is someone who can help me with this.

Comment: **(1)** Try [Youtube-DL for PHP](https://www.google.com/search?q=Youtube-DL+for+PHP). It will extract the current working links to the MP4 on Youtube servers (because links always expire in few hours). **(2)** Why not just save the video (using online Youtube downloader) and keep it on your server?

Comment: Hi VC.One, thanks for your comment, but did you now how i can build this code in my website? I have more than one video to download for the website and I tested a example and rhis code doesen't work for my. I hope you can help me with that.

Comment: What video link did you try so I can check things for you?

Comment: I don't just want to convert a special link, I want to convert everything on my website that my customers can specifically enter themselves

Comment: Youtube-DL seems to have changed. It used to be a PHP script but now it seems to be a Python app that runs on command line. I don't know how to install Python scripts on a server (or whether the server type matters, _eg:_ Apache, Windows, Linux).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, but i doesn't find this sources to get the videos

Comment: I don't understand... **(1)** You need sources of Youtube-DL (a download link for the app)? Or **(2)** You already have Youtube-DL but when you use, it does not find videos?... What did you try that is not working (also add your tested video link)?